# How to Fix GeoServer Logging XML Validation Errors

Tags: geoserver, xml

I am running GeoServer Version 2.20.1. I'm not sure if it is important or not, but I'm running GeoServer as a .war file in JBoss EAP 7.4. When I create and update Image Mosaics using the REST api the following errors are logged.

```
2023-05-23 16:42:43,980 ERROR [stderr] - Warning: validation was turned on but an org.xml.sax.ErrorHandler was not
2023-05-23 16:42:43,995 ERROR [stderr] - set, which is probably not what is desired.  Parser will use a default
2023-05-23 16:42:44,006 ERROR [stderr] - ErrorHandler to print the first 10 errors.  Please call
2023-05-23 16:42:44,010 ERROR [stderr] - the 'setErrorHandler' method to fix this.
2023-05-23 16:42:44,025 ERROR [stderr] - Error: URI=null Line=1: Document root element "coverageStores", must match DOCTYPE root "null".
2023-05-23 16:42:44,037 ERROR [stderr] - Error: URI=null Line=1: Document is invalid: no grammar found.
2023-05-23 16:42:44,055 ERROR [stderr] - Warning: validation was turned on but an org.xml.sax.ErrorHandler was not
2023-05-23 16:42:44,075 ERROR [stderr] - set, which is probably not what is desired.  Parser will use a default
```

I don't ever pass in XML with coverageStores in it so I am fairly confident it is not an input data issue.

Is there a configuration change that I can make to turn on an ErrorHandler? Is there another way to fix/prevent these errors?

Comment: could be related to the Log4J changes and you're the first JBoss user to look at the log, best place to ask is the GeoServer user list.

Comment: Thanks @IanTurton I'll send a question to the user list